# ##[error]No file matched with specific pattern: /appsettings.json

Tags: github-actions

After reading this answer:[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60913464/13577337)

I tried to do the same.

I have a .net core project and in my case, I am using a repo with a publish version so my `appsettings.json` is in the root of the repo.

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: DeployToStaging

# Controls when the action will run. Triggers the workflow on push or pull request
# events but only for the master branch
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [assigned, opened, synchronize, reopened]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  FTP-Deploy-Action:
    name: FTP-Deploy-Action
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
      with:
        fetch-depth: 2
    - uses: microsoft/variable-substitution@v1
      with:
        files: '${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/appsettings.json'
      env:
        ConnectionStrings.ToBudget: 'This is just a test'
    - name: FTP Deploy
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.1.0
      with:
        ftp-server: <MyServer>
        # FTP account username
        ftp-username: <MyUsername>
        ftp-password: ${{ secrets.FtpPassword }}
```

So basically I want to transform my connection string (for now it is just a test, in the future I will create a secret) and then push it to the server through FTP.

Everything is working except the variable substitution. The error is: No file matched with specific pattern: `/appsettings.json`

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the issue.
instead of files: '${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/appsettings.json' I just need to do files: 'appsettings.json'

Now I am having a second issue. SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.1.0 doesn't like the change. It is avoiding uploading because the repo is dirty.

EDIT: regarding the second issue I moved to [sebastionpopp/ftpaction](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ftp-action)